# Select random table

Tags: mysql

I want to select a random rows from a random table from my database.
I searched on net but everything is about selecting random rows from a table. I know it sounds weird, but I need it as I need to poll random data across tables and  will appreciate if anyone can help me.

Thanks

**EDIT**
Since I have got four down votes within seconds :), thought I will just illustrate my reason for the same:

I need to select 100 days' (random 100 days in sequence) stock price for a random stock. Each table represents daily price for a particular stock. Now I need a way to select a stock in random.

Comment: Have a look at INFORMATION_SCHEMA for selecting random tables

Comment: let me know why do you need to do this ?? is ther any server side language involved ?

Comment: @X-Factor: I need to select 100 days' (random 100 days in sequence) stock price for a random stock. Each table represents daily price for a particular stock.

Comment: I would argue that it's flawed design to have a table for each stock. I'd fix this by creating a view over all stock tables and randomly select from this view ... but that's really just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table_name, engine
FROM information_schema.tables    
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema='database_name'  
order by rand()
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables ORDER BY RAND()
```

Now just limit it to the database or other preference.